# install SVN Client on CentOS with ssh

Tags: svn, centos, client

friends. I was trying to install an svn client on my server using this tutorial, but when I try to run *.rpm files, I receive the error shown below.

```
    libapr-1.so.0 is needed by mod_dav_svn-1.8.4-2.i686  
    libaprutil-1.so.0 is needed by mod_dav_svn-1.8.4-2.i686  
    libdb-4.7.so is needed by mod_dav_svn-1.8.4-2.i686  
    libexpat.so.1 is needed by mod_dav_svn-1.8.4-2.i686  
    rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1 is needed by mod_dav_svn-1.8.4-2.i686  
    rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1 is needed by mod_dav_svn-1.8.4-2.i686  
    libapr-1.so.0 is needed by serf-1.3.2-2.i686  
    libaprutil-1.so.0 is needed by serf-1.3.2-2.i686  
    libcrypto.so.10 is needed by serf-1.3.2-2.i686  
    libdb-4.7.so is needed by serf-1.3.2-2.i686  
    libexpat.so.1 is needed by serf-1.3.2-2.i686  
    liblber-2.4.so.2 is needed by serf-1.3.2-2.i686  
    libldap-2.4.so.2 is needed by serf-1.3.2-2.i686  
    libssl.so.10 is needed by serf-1.3.2-2.i686  
    rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1 is needed by serf-1.3.2-2.i686  
    rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1 is needed by serf-1.3.2-2.i686  
    libapr-1.so.0 is needed by subversion-1.8.4-2.i686  
    libaprutil-1.so.0 is needed by subversion-1.8.4-2.i686  
    libdb-4.7.so is needed by subversion-1.8.4-2.i686  
    libexpat.so.1 is needed by subversion-1.8.4-2.i686  
    libsasl2.so.2 is needed by subversion-1.8.4-2.i686  
    rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1 is needed by subversion-1.8.4-2.i686  
    rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1 is needed by subversion-1.8.4-2.i686  
    libapr-1.so.0 is needed by subversion-gnome-1.8.4-2.i686  
    libaprutil-1.so.0 is needed by subversion-gnome-1.8.4-2.i686  
    libdb-4.7.so is needed by subversion-gnome-1.8.4-2.i686  
    libexpat.so.1 is needed by subversion-gnome-1.8.4-2.i686  
    libglib-2.0.so.0 is needed by subversion-gnome-1.8.4-2.i686  
    libgnome-keyring.so.0 is needed by subversion-gnome-1.8.4-2.i686  
    rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1 is needed by subversion-gnome-1.8.4-2.i686  
    rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1 is needed by subversion-gnome-1.8.4-2.i686  
    libapr-1.so.0 is needed by subversion-javahl-1.8.4-2.i686  
    libaprutil-1.so.0 is needed by subversion-javahl-1.8.4-2.i686  
    libdb-4.7.so is needed by subversion-javahl-1.8.4-2.i686  
    libexpat.so.1 is needed by subversion-javahl-1.8.4-2.i686  
    libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.11) is needed by subversion-javahl-1.8.4-2.i686  
    libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.9) is needed by subversion-javahl-1.8.4-2.i686  
    rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1 is needed by subversion-javahl-1.8.4-2.i686  
    rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1 is needed by subversion-javahl-1.8.4-2.i686  
    libapr-1.so.0 is needed by subversion-perl-1.8.4-2.i686  
    libaprutil-1.so.0 is needed by subversion-perl-1.8.4-2.i686  
    libdb-4.7.so is needed by subversion-perl-1.8.4-2.i686  
    libexpat.so.1 is needed by subversion-perl-1.8.4-2.i686  
    rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1 is needed by subversion-perl-1.8.4-2.i686  
    rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1 is needed by subversion-perl-1.8.4-2.i686  
    libapr-1.so.0 is needed by subversion-python-1.8.4-2.i686  
    libaprutil-1.so.0 is needed by subversion-python-1.8.4-2.i686  
    libdb-4.7.so is needed by subversion-python-1.8.4-2.i686  
    libexpat.so.1 is needed by subversion-python-1.8.4-2.i686  
    python(abi) = 2.6 is needed by subversion-python-1.8.4-2.i686  
    rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1 is needed by subversion-python-1.8.4-2.i686  
    rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1 is needed by subversion-python-1.8.4-  2.i686  
    libapr-1.so.0 is needed by subversion-tools-1.8.4-2.i686  
    libaprutil-1.so.0 is needed by subversion-tools-1.8.4-2.i686  
    libdb-4.7.so is needed by subversion-tools-1.8.4-2.i686  
    libexpat.so.1 is needed by subversion-tools-1.8.4-2.i686  
    rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1 is needed by subversion-tools-1.8.4-   2.i686  
    rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1 is needed by subversion-tools-1.8.4-2.i686
```

I'm not sure what's wrong, but please let me know what I need to fix! Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks above issue resolved using below command

```
yum install subversion
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the RPM files that provide the missing libraries.

The best option to install subversion is to use the CentOS software administration tool that automatically determines the dependencies and marks the package for installation along SVN. You should be able to find this in the desktop menu (exact location depends on CentOS version).

As an alternative you might use yum, which is also able to automatically resolve the dependencies.

As second alternative you may install the RPMs manually. Usually they are named like the libs they contain. E.g. the RPM containing libexpat.so.1 should be named expat-* or libexpat-*.
So you would have to work through the list of dependencies and then install one after the other. If you are unsure about the order provide all of the *.rpms on the same command line, then RPM will determine the order automatically.

Comment: i am following this ref. link : http://snowdream.github.io/blog/centos/2013/11/08/how-to-install-subversion-18-on-centos-64/ which giving above error